# Where is my Tomcat running on my virtual server?

Tags: apache, localhost, tomcat

According to what I know; Apache and Tomcat are listing on different ports by default. If I have both of them running locally then:

- localhost -> Apache home page (port 80)
- localhost:8080" -> Tomcat home page

Now we are writing a web project hosted virtual server and we have got an got a URL like  `http://SOMESERVER:8013` which redirects to our Apache home page.

Note: We use port 8013 since we are group 13 and other numbers goes to other groups, and a group can't access others' machines.

I think it is working like when a request goes to SOMESERVER on port 8013, it is redirected to our virtual machine (on port80 maybe? I tried `telnet localhost 80` and `GET /` gives me Apache homepage.

If I start up Tomcat with the default configuration where can I find my Tomcat's home page? `http://SOMESERVER:8013:8080` is not working anyways...

Comment: Is "http: //SOMESERVER:8013:8080" a typo ? should be  "http: //SOMESERVER:8080"

Comment: "http: //SOMESERVER" is a central server which we can't change things. "http://SOMESERVER:8013" is redirected to our virtual machine. If Tomcat is running on SOMSERVER, then it would be ""http: //SOMESERVER:8080". However, Tomcat is running on our virtual machine...

Comment: You need to talk to your host/server admin about this. You've already mentioned one custom port. Besides the "usual" ones like 8080, nobody on this side of things is going to know what they might've been set to.

Answer (score 1):

If port 8013 is your tomcat server's HTTP connector port (and it is hard for me to tell based on your description), you can place your default homepage within `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/ROOT/`.  Once you replace that page, requests to `http://someserver:8013/` would display your new default page.